# Office Outlook 12 Interop DLL Dependencies

Tags: c#, interop, outlook, installation, project

I just finished a project using Outlook interop to send emails, and i'm wondering if, if i run it in any computer having the same version 12, would it be ok ?

if not can i just build my project in the develeopment pc, and add a setup project ? in this case how can i tell the setup project to include all the outlook office 12 files ?

thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference the Office Interop libraries, by default the interop types are embedded into your assembly. As long as your users have the same (or in most cases a later) version of Word installed, they shouldn't need anything else.

A suggestion; if the same functionality you are using is part of earlier Office versions, the COM model is backwards-compatible. So, you could reference the Office 11 (2007) version of the Visual Studio Tools for Office, and it would also work with Office 12 (2010).

Comment: i still have that error, even if i made a setup project with all dependencies from default output, for exe and dlls